# Asynchronous iteratee processing in Scalaz

Tags: scala, asynchronous, scalaz, loops

I've been using Scalaz 7 iteratees to process a large (i.e., unbounded) stream of data in constant heap space.

In code, it looks something like this:

```
type ErrorOrT[M[+_], A] = EitherT[M, Throwable, A]
type ErrorOr[A] = ErrorOrT[IO, A]

def processChunk(c: Chunk): Result

def process(data: EnumeratorT[Chunk, ErrorOr]): IterateeT[Chunk, ErrorOr, List[Result]] =
  Iteratee.fold[Chunk, ErrorOr, List[Result]](Nil) { (rs, c) =>
    processChunk(c) :: rs
  } &= data
```

Now I'd like to perform the processing in parallel, working on *P* chunks of data at a time. I still have to limit heap space, but it's reasonable to assume that there's enough heap to store *P* chunks of data and the accumulated results of the computation.

I'm aware of the `Task` class and thought of mapping over the enumerator to create a stream of tasks:

```
data map (c => Task.delay(processChunk(c)))
```

But I'm still not sure how to manage the non-determinism. **While consuming the stream, how do I ensure that *P* tasks are running whenever possible?**

**First try:**

My first stab at a solution was to fold over the stream and create a Scala `Future` to process each chunk. However, the program blew up with a GC overhead error (presumably because it was pulling all the chunks into memory as it tried to create all the `Future`s). Instead, the iteratee needs to stop consuming input when there are already *P* tasks running and resume again when any of the those tasks finish.

**Second try:**

My next attempt was to group the stream into *P*-sized parts, process each part in parallel, then join before moving on to the next part:

```
def process(data: EnumeratorT[Chunk, ErrorOr]): IterateeT[Chunk, ErrorOr, Vector[Result]] =
  Iteratee.foldM[Vector[Chunk], ErrorOr, Vector[Result]](Nil) { (rs, cs) =>
    tryIO(IO(rs ++ Await.result(
      Future.traverse(cs) { 
        c => Future(processChunk(c)) 
      }, 
      Duration.Inf)))
  } &= (data mapE Iteratee.group(P))
```

While this wouldn't fully utilize the available processors (especially since the time required to process each `Chunk` may vary widely), it would be an improvement. However, [the `group` enumeratee seems to leak memory -- heap usage suddenly goes through the roof](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19128856/avoiding-memory-leaks-with-scalaz-7-iteratees).

Comment: FYI, play iteratees (which are based off scala futures) had memory leaks as well. This situation [was fixed recently](https://github.com/scala/scala/pull/2674)

Comment: @om-nom-nom The memory leak seems to be unrelated to the use of Scala Futures. See [this related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19128856/avoiding-memory-leaks-with-scalaz-7-iteratees).

Comment: actually wanted to post comment to that question :-) Just saying that scalaz futures and scala futures could have the same flaw conceptually