# Why does this Scalaz 7 enumerator leak memory?

Tags: scala, memory-leaks, scalaz, loops, scalaz7

The following definition results in a memory leak:

```
def enumIterator1[E, F[_]: Monad](x: => Iterator[E]) : EnumeratorT[E, F] =
  new EnumeratorT[E, F] {
    def apply[A] = (s: StepT[E, F, A]) => {
      def go(xs: Iterator[E]): IterateeT[E, F, A] =
        if(xs.isEmpty) s.pointI
        else {
          val next = xs.next
          s mapCont { k => 
            k(Iteratee.elInput(next)) >>== enumIterator1[E, F](xs).apply[A] 
          }
        }
      go(x)
    }
  }
```

The leak can be observed with the following test:

```
(Iteratee.fold[Array[Byte], IO, Long](0L)(_+_.length) 
  &= enumIterator1(
    Iterator.continually(
      Array.fill(1 << 16)(0.toByte)).take(1 << 16))
).run.unsafePerformIO
```

However, a minor change (i.e., moving the `xs.next` call) stops the leak:

```
def enumIterator1[E, F[_]: Monad](x: => Iterator[E]) : EnumeratorT[E, F] =
  new EnumeratorT[E, F] {
    def apply[A] = (s: StepT[E, F, A]) => {
      def go(xs: Iterator[E]): IterateeT[E, F, A] =
        if(xs.isEmpty) s.pointI
        else {
          // val next = xs.next (moved down)
          s mapCont { k => 
            val next = xs.next
            k(Iteratee.elInput(next)) >>== enumIterator1[E, F](xs).apply[A] 
          }
        }
      go(x)
    }
  }
```

**Why?**

I have a vague notion that the explanation has to do with the reference pattern of the closures, but I can't **come up with a specific reason for this behavior**. I'm trying to track down [a different memory leak](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19128856/avoiding-memory-leaks-with-scalaz-7-zipwithindex-group-enumeratees), and I suspect (*hope?*) that understanding *this leak* may help to identify the cause of that one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that the anonymous function passed to `mapCont` closes over `next`. In turn, this is closed-over by the lazy variable we pass to enumIterator, which is closed-over by the new `Enumerator` formed by `enumIterator1`, which is closed-over by the anonymous function in `apply`, which is finally closed-over by the anonymous function passed to `mapCont` for the next iteration.

So, by a chain of closures, each enumerator closes over its predecessor. This would probably happen whether `next` was captured or not, so you'd have a minor memory leak either way. However, you end up capturing `next` in one of these closures, which means that every value generated by your iterator stays in memory until the whole process is complete (and these values take up a lot of memory).

By moving `next` inside the anonymous function passed to `mapCont`, `next` is not captured in our chain of closures any more, so the main memory leak disappears (although your closures still close over each other, which may be a concern).

The best way to fix this is probably to simplify it. As Brian Kernighan famously said:

> Everyone knows that debugging is twice as hard as writing a program in the first place. So if you're as clever as you can be when you write it, how will you ever debug it?

I'm not certain I fully understand the code, but I suspect the following is equivalent:

```
def enumIterator1[E, F[_]: Monad](x: => Iterator[E]) : EnumeratorT[E, F] =
  new EnumeratorT[E, F] {
    def apply[A] = {
      val xs = x
      def innerApply(s: StepT[E, F, A]): IterateeT[E, F, A] = {
        if(xs.isEmpty) s.pointI
        else {
          val next = xs.next
          s mapCont { cont => // renamed k to cont, as the function, rather than the variable, is k
            cont(Iteratee.elInput(next)) >>== innerApply
          }
        }
      }
      innerApply
    }
  }
```

You might also benefit from making things more explicit. For example, what if rather than having an anonymous `EnumeratorT` that implicitly closes over anything it needs within its scope, you define a named class, with top level scope, and pass in anything it needs explicitly.

I used `-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError`, VisualVM, and `javap` to find the cause of the issue. They should be everything you need.

### Update

I *think* I'm starting to grok what the code's supposed to do, and I've updated my code accordingly. I think the problem was the use of `enumIterator1[E, F](xs).apply[A]`. The code was creating a new `EnumeratorT` just to get at its apply method, but creating a by-name variable and closing over everything-and-its-dog in the process. Since the value of `xs` doesn't change from one recursion to the next, we create an `innerApply` method which closes over the val `xs`, and re-use `innerApply`.

### Update 2

I was curious, so I had a look around in the Scalaz source to see how they solve this problem. Here's some code with a similar bent from Scalaz itself:

```
def enumIterator[E, F[_]](x: => Iterator[E])(implicit MO: MonadPartialOrder[F, IO]) : EnumeratorT[E, F] =
  new EnumeratorT[E, F] {
    import MO._ // Remove this line, and you can copy and paste it into your code
    def apply[A] = {
      def go(xs: Iterator[E])(s: StepT[E, F, A]): IterateeT[E, F, A] =
        if(xs.isEmpty) s.pointI
        else {
          s mapCont { k => 
            val next = xs.next
            k(elInput(next)) >>== go(xs)
          }
        }
      go(x)
    }
  }
```

They use currying, rather than closure, to capture `xs`, but it's still an "inner apply" approach.

Comment: I'm trying to follow that chain of closures, and I can't wrap my head around the second step. Why does the anonymous function argument of `mapCont` get closed over by the by-name argument to `enumIterator1`? (I assume you meant `enumIterator1` rather than `enumIterator`)

Comment: I might have made a mistake, but IIRC it's because it finds `xs` via `outer$`.

Comment: That makes some sense, I suppose, but it seems like it must be a compiler bug then. Closures shouldn't hold references that they never use. Thanks for tracking this down. I plan to verify your explanation within the next couple days, then award the tick and bounty.

Comment: The suggested implementation is *not* equivalent, by the way. It's essential for the Iterator to be a by-name argument in order to use `enumIterator1` in functional code. Unlike Iterators, Enumerators are reusable, so correct usage of `enumIterator1` involves passing a function that constructs an Iterator rather than passing the Iterator itself.

Comment: I suspected my code was different in some subtle way - my experience with iteratees is from Play, which has some subtle differences. You should probably check my working on the chain of closures as well - my approach was basically to follow the references in the heap dump, and try to figure out what the corresponding classes do by looking at them in `javap`. But either way, simplifying should make things clearer.

Comment: just saw your updates. Regarding the second update, the commit history of  `EnumeratorT.scala` might be informative. Specifically, [these](https://github.com/scalaz/scalaz/commit/7033b241c1745ed45dc4546d20b7b3c9bd31f942) [commits](https://github.com/scalaz/scalaz/commit/79ae647c63f8b50c63620cae18f1e92a80fed635). ;-)

Comment: I've determined that this answer is awesome for at least two reasons: first, because it *finally* helped me understand why this happens and why it's *not* a compiler bug, and second, because the advice to simplify was so spot-on. I *had* simplified the scalaz code just because it didn't make sense to me -- but I didn't realize at the time that the simplification alone would have fixed the leak! Bounty to you, sir!